# All hotkeys disabled

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys, eclipse-3.5

I've somehow managed to disable all hotkeys in eclipse Galileo running on Ubuntu Maverick, and I'd really like to enable them again.  For example, if I want to rename a variable, normally I'd use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, or to jump to a function declaration I'd use <kbd>F3</kbd>.

I can still right-click on a variable/function name and perform these actions successfully.  In fact, when I right click to bring up the context menu, it displays a tip next to each option saying what hotkey is assigned, but the tips are greyed out as if to indicate they're disabled.

I was messing around with some of my preferences earlier, and I probably hit something by accident, but I can't find which one.  Any help you can give would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that anyone is overly curious, but just in case:

The problem I was having was completely unrelated to eclipse.  I use a keyboard where the function keys have a modifier key that I accidentally hit sometimes.  I never intentionally hit it, so when my function keys stop working, it always takes me some time to figure out what's going on.  Once I set my keyboard back to "use function keys for what they're really supposed to be used for," everything started working like magic.

Oh well.  Live and learn and forget and relearn.